# Determine the limit to which $\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\left (1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right )$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Background: this is Arfken et al mathematical methods 12.5.4 and the answer is 1.

Using the infinite sin product we need the alternating terms in red to cancel when $\pi$ is plugged into z but I don't know how to do that:

$$\frac{\sin(z)}{z(1-z^2/\pi^2)}=\prod_{\color{red}{n=2}}^{\infty}(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2})\overset{z=\pi}{=}\color{red}{(1-\frac{1}{2})}(1+\frac{1}{2})\color{red}{(1+\frac{1}{3})}(1-\frac{1}{3})\color{red}{(1-\frac{1}{4})}(1+\frac{1}{4})\dots$$

Alternate answers using other values for z like $\pi i/2$ or using other infinite series like cos are welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is here, especially after that last sentence. Why are you getting two of each term? Also, you use an implication symbol but don't have an equality after it, just a product

Comment: I picked the z value of $\pi$ but cheating and knowing the answer is 1 might mean a value of $\pi i /2 $ would be helpful or possibly the infinite product can be evaluated using an infinite product series other than sin(z). There are two terms because I factored the difference of squares.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The product of all red terms is

\begin{align*}
&(1-\frac12)(1+\frac13)(1-\frac14)(1+\frac15)(1-\frac16)\cdots\\
=\ &\frac12\cdot\frac43\cdot\frac34\cdot\frac65\cdot\frac56\cdots
\end{align*}

Therefore, 
$$\prod_{n=2}^m\left(1+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n\right)\ =\ \left\{\begin{matrix}
\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac{m+1}m\quad(m\ \text{is odd})\\\\
\dfrac12\quad\ \ (m\ \text{is even}) 
\end{matrix}\right.\\$$
If $m$ tends to infinity, the product will tend to $\dfrac12$ in both cases, so we have
$$\frac12\ =\ \lim_{z\rightarrow\pi}\frac{\sin(z)}{\ z(1-z^2/\pi^2)\ }\ =\ \prod_{n=2}^\infty\left(1+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n\right)\cdot\prod_{n=2}^\infty\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}n\right)\ =\ \frac12\prod_{n=2}^\infty\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}n\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow\quad\prod_{n=2}^\infty\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}n\right)\ =\ 1\\$$

(This answer has been corrected according to the suggestions from Masacroso)

Comment: rearranging terms is not correct, in general, to show convergence for infinite products (specifically in this case neither). By example the infinite product $$\prod_{k=1}^\infty \big(k+\mathbf 1_{2\Bbb N}(k)\big)^{(-1)^k}$$ diverges (where $\mathbf 1_A$ is an indicator function), but if you pair elements it seems that converges. In the above case the infinite sequence convergence because it is equivalent to the sequence $$\frac12,\;\frac12{\cdot} \frac43,\;\frac12,\; \frac12{\cdot} \frac65,\;\frac12,\; \frac12{\cdot} \frac87,\;\ldots$$

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks a lot for pointing out this mistake :) I will edit my answer

Answer (score 5):

Here's a different approach notice that for $n=2k$
we have that the general term is equal to
$$\frac{2k+(-1)^{2k}}{2k}=\frac{2k+1}{2k}$$
And for $n=2k+1$ we have $$\frac{2k+1+(-1)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}=\frac{2k}{2k+1}$$
And the product of those two is exactly $1$,hence writing the partial product
$$P_{2k+2}=\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{5}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdots\frac{2k+1}{2k}\cdot\frac{2k}{2k+1}\cdot\frac{2k+3}{2k+2}=\frac{2k+3}{2k+2}$$
and $$P_{2k+1}=1$$
So we have that $P_n\to1$ as $n\to\infty$ so the product converges to $1$.